# Replace UIRefreshControl with UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UIRefreshControl` in my `UITableView`. I want to replace the system's refresh icon with my own. I've tried just adding a subview to the refreshControl like so...

```
    let refreshImage = UIImageView()
    refreshImage.image = UIImage(named: "RefreshIcon")
    refreshControl.insertSubview(refreshImage, at: 0)
    tableview.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

But that did not work. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: try refreshImage.frame = refreshControl.bounds, refreshControl.addSubview(refreshImage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
 let refreshImage = UIImageView()
    refreshImage.image = UIImage(named: "RefreshIcon")
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    refreshControl.addSubview(refreshImage)
    tableview.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

and then to center it to the top, you can use this:

```
    refreshImage.frame = refreshControl.bounds.offsetBy(dx: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 20 // half the width of the refreshImage, dy: 10)
    refreshImage.frame.size.width = 40 // Whatever width you want
    refreshImage.frame.size.height = 40 // Whatever height you want
```

Comment: Ok, so that worked, but the image is stretched across the screen. The image is a square. So, I replaced `refreshImage.frame = refreshControl.bounds` with `refreshImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)`. But nothing showed up lol.

Comment: it's working from my side when I set this refreshImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20), This show the at corner to the refresh header. I am using the jpg format image @JacobCavin

Comment: Use the image name with a format like RefreshIcon.png , Whatever your format @JacobCavin

Comment: I just need to center the image to the x of the screen and at the top of the screen.

Comment: Yes, exactly, then the image show or not? @JacobCavin

Comment: Ok. I put it in the right position by going like this `refreshImage.frame = refreshControl.bounds.offsetBy(dx: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 20, dy: 10)
        refreshImage.frame.size.width = 40
        refreshImage.frame.size.height = 40`